# Is there a way to find out what is the name of an icon that is on the bottom bar, on Gnome 3?  

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, system-tray, messaging-tray

Is there a way to find out what is the name of an icon that is on the bottom bar, on Gnome 3?

For example, the name of the icon of Audacious is `audacious`, for Dropbox it's `dropbox`... I need their names to write them down on the Status Icon Fixer extension for Gnome 3.

I have tried:

StatusIconDispatcher.STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS['LibreOffice 3.5 Quickstarter'] = 'LibreOffice 3.5 Quickstarter';

But it didn't work.

I need the name for the Google Chrome background tray icon and LibreOffice 3.5 Quickstarter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Got the LibreOffice 3.5 Quickstarter's name from System Monitor and Google's Chrome is google-chrome.

Add:

```
StatusIconDispatcher.STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS['soffice'] = 'soffice';
StatusIconDispatcher.STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS['google-chrome'] = 'google-chrome';
```

to:

```
.../gnome-shell/extensions/status@gnome-shell.2jk.org/extension.js
```

Still have found no way to grab the names from icons.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely taken from https://github.com/brianhsu/EvilStatusIconForever

Therefore, credits go to brianhsu.

> This may borken your GNOME, BE CAREFUL AND BACKUP FIRST!!!! You need
>   root premission to do this. Edit
>   /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/statusIconDispatcher.js
>
> Move to line 48,
>   you should see a function called _onTrayIconAdded which look like the
>   following:
>
> ```
> _onTrayIconAdded: function(o, icon) {
>     let wmClass = (icon.wm_class || 'unknown').toLowerCase();
>     let role = STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS[wmClass];
>     if (role)
>         this.emit('status-icon-added', icon, role);
>     else
>         this.emit('message-icon-added', icon);
> },
> ```
>
> Add global.log("wmClass[] = " + wmClass); after the line of let role = ..., now this function should look like the following:
>
> ```
> _onTrayIconAdded: function(o, icon) {
>     let wmClass = (icon.wm_class || 'unknown').toLowerCase();
>     let role = STANDARD_TRAY_ICON_IMPLEMENTATIONS[wmClass];
>     global.log("wmClass[] = " + wmClass);
>     if (role)
>         this.emit('status-icon-added', icon, role);
>     else
>         this.emit('message-icon-added', icon); },
> ```
>
> Restart GNOME 3 by press Alt + F2 and r and hit enter.
>
> Start GNOME console by press Alt + F2 and lg and hit enter.
>
> Switch to Errors tab, now you should see message like the following:
>
> > wmClass[] = pidgin

... which is the icon name to be used in Status Icon Fixer.

Comment: Good lord! :|

It might work, but isn't there a much more simpler way?

Comment: It works but indeed this is not trivial. I don't know any simpler way, this is definitely something to be worked on by Gnome-shell devs...